# Problem on Android 12 when closing and restarting App

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Based on this code, I close my App for some reason and then run it again. This works perfectly on Android below 10.

But on Android above 10, my App doesn't restart again.

All permissions are granted for Android 12 at design-time and run-time.

```
procedure ReStartApp;
var
  LPM : JPackageManager;
  LIntent_Start : JIntent;
  LPendingIntent : JPendingIntent;
  LMS : Int64;
begin    
  LPM := TAndroidHelper.Context.getPackageManager();
  LIntent_Start := LPM.getLaunchIntentForPackage(
      TAndroidHelper.Context.getPackageName()
      );
  LIntent_Start.addFlags( TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );

  LPendingIntent := TJPendingIntent.JavaClass.getActivity(
      TAndroidHelper.Context,
      223344 {RequestCode},
      LIntent_Start,
      TJPendingIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
      );
  LMS := DateTimeToUnix( Now, False {InputIsUTC} ) * 1000;

  TAndroidHelper.AlarmManager.&set(
      TJAlarmManager.JavaClass.RTC,
      LMS + 10000,
      LPendingIntent
      );
      // TAndroidHelper.Activity.finish();
    Application.Terminate;
end;
```

Comment: Could be due to [Restrictions on starting activities from the background](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts) introduced in Android 10.

Comment: @AlexSawers base your link I add  SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW to permission of my app. but had no effect. I enable "Display over other apps" on some of mobile manually and problem solved. how can do this setting programmatically.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to enable such permission programmatically as it was designed for the user to enable it manually -to prevent apps taking over the screen spontaneously when the device is in use-.